# Probability that a sample drawn from one distribution is lower than a sample drawn from another distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, kurtosis, stochastic-ordering

Context: we don't know the exact distribution parameters, however in practice
we can obtain many samples from each distribution.

Case 1: let's say that I have a sample of size N from each distribution.
Let's say N=1000 would be realistic and doable in practice.

Case 2: let's say that we only have a sample of size N from the left tail of each distribution.

I guess those are standard statistical tests, but I am not sure which ones.

Bonus point if the calculation is really fast, because this will be needed to compare
thousands of samples.

Comment: What is your research question? Testing whether the mean of two distributions is different? In case 1 you would sample from your population, while in case 2 you would sample from the lower tail of the population only and compare whether the mean of this is different?

Comment: My "research question" (as you call it) is: which distribution dominates the other; by dominance I mean one distribution has consistently lower extreme values compared to the other distribution (I am only seriously considering Case 2).

Comment: this may require complex integral calculations and some other assumptions about distributions, rather than statistical tests

Comment: By "dominance" would [first-order stochastic dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance#First-order) capture what you want, or are you interested in something else?

Comment: first-order stochastic dominance looks too strong, but I am certainly interested by something related to stochastic ordering.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is straightforward and intuitive.

repeat the following process N times

- sample from distribution 1, denoted as x
- sample from distribution 2, denoted as y
- if x < y return 1 else return 0

count(x < y) / N is the probability of you need

Comment: Yes, such a procedure is indeed interesting, but this is not as efficient to compute as what I am expecting.

Comment: Maybe I am just interested by the Mann-Whitney U statistic, but it looks like it has O(N^2) complexity. cf. method 1 in calculations in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test

Comment: That doesn't address the focus of the question, which is on the lower tail of the distribution.

Comment: The runtime of Mann-Whitney with sample sizes of 1000 isn't an issue on anything resembling a modern computer.

Comment: does left tail of distribution mean something like truncated distribution?

Comment: I guess that if we consider only the N lowest samples of a distribution, then the distribution is truncated.

Comment: FYI, In Thompson Sampling, has the same question of determining the probability that each arm is the best in a multi-arm distribution,  and is often achieved through simulating samples from each arm distribution for practical calculation